# Is it meaningful to perform statistical methods after multidimensional scaling?

Tags: machine-learning, multidimensional-scaling

Suppose I have data which I want to cluster, for example. I am not sure that the data are Euclidean i.e. they are really points in a Euclidean space with Euclidean metric. So I can try to first perform multidimensional scaling to get a Euclidean representation, and then do usual k-means clustering on this representation. Is this a meaningful idea? It just seems to me that since MDS respects the original (non-Euclidean) distance matrix, clustering by k-means would yield similar result both before and after MDS.

Similarly, once I do get Euclidean data after doing MDS, can I do PCA, ICA, etc. because these depend on the variances, and variance is associated with Euclidean distance?

Comment: if it's not euclidian only in sense of scale, then would Mahalonobis distance for you?

Comment: Sorry I do not follow your comment.

Comment: Is the scale difference the only aspect that makes this non Euclidian? Is there anything else that makes it non Euclidian? The scale truly is a problem when your variable are measured in different units such as kg and m. It's weird to measure distance as $\sqrt{kg^2+m^2}$, but I see that sometimes people freak out about the scales when variables simply have different dispersions

Comment: Think of data on the surface of a sphere. That's genuinely non-Euclidean, and presumably your Mahalanobis distance won't work.

Comment: Maybe then you need to look at the suitable distance metric. For instance, on a sphere it could be the great circle distance, [haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). I'm afraid there's no generic answer to your question.